# How can I fit a model to experimental data using Debye's equation either in Matlab or Python

Tags: optimization, model, curve-fitting, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to fit a model to my experimental data of complex value of the type R + jX.

To be more precise, I have experimental data on water at 20 deg Centigrade. The data are collected over limited frequency values from 200MHz to 6GHz and another taken from published work. However, the model I have chosen is Debye model which is  of the form:

E’ = E (infinity) – [E (static) – E (infinity) ] / (1 + (wt) 2

Where E’ is the complex permittivity (Real part), E (infinity) is the permittivity at optical frequency or infinite frequency and E (static) is the static permittivity at very low frequency or when the
frequency tends to zero, w is defined as omega 2*pi*frequency and ‘t’ is the relaxation time

1. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V7SVzpiA95Oc0m_yNvV1gBdtTSPjBBSs/view?usp=sharing - For water (H2O) at 20 deg C
2. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BHHNlT2XmItGOanGl0xsyFjifPHor6To/view?usp=sharing - from another source but different data set

Experimental data supplied.

These values are expected to be E (static) = 80.2 or thereabout (0.2 margin), E (infinity = 5.2 and t = 9.36 exp -12

ps. I have tried this in matlab using variant equation such as

**Problem in Matlab**
a+(b-a)/1+(2*3.142*x*c)^2 and variant a+(b-a)/(1+(2*3.142*x*c)^2)^d) but there was no
convergence to the actual data.

**Problem in Python**
a+(b-a)/1+(2*3.142*x*c)^2 using the above equation as in Matlab but this time in Python,
the E (static) was as expected 80.2, however other values are inaccurate (see below), I seems to
have better success using the variant equation a+(b-a)/(1+(2*3.142*x*c)^2)^d
**Below are my results in Python using the above fitting model**
80.29080554191091
1.0
1.8969872910331487e-11
1.0000322206749337
Solution and suggestions welcome,

Here is the code, but the experimental data is a bit long, therefore, I have supplied the link to a google storage.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#import libraries
import numpy as np
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

#define constant e0
e0=0.000000000008845
pi=3.14159625

#import csv file
with open("water.csv", "r") as i:
    rawdata = list(csv.reader(i,delimiter=","))
    
experimentdata = np.array(rawdata[1:],dtype=float)
frequencydata = experimentdata[:,0]
rpermdata = experimentdata[:,1]
conductivitydata = experimentdata[:,2]

conductivity = 2*pi*e0*frequencydata*10**6*conductivitydata
#frequency_multiplied = np.multiply(frequencydata, 10**6)

#plot data - change colours?
plt.figure(1,dpi=120)
plt.title("Fitted model for group I phantom design.")
plt.xlabel("Frequency (MHz)")
plt.ylabel("Relative permittivity")
#plt.xlim(0,3)
#plt.ylim(0,3)
plt.xscale("linear")
plt.yscale("linear")
plt.scatter(frequencydata,rpermdata,color='yellow',label="r-perm") #comment this line out to just see conductivity
plt.scatter(frequencydata,conductivitydata,color="orange",label="cond") #comment this line out to just see relative permittivity

#define function - needs tweaking?
def model(x,p1,p2,p3,p4):
   return(p2+(p1-p2)/(1+(p3*x)**p4))

#def model(x,p1,p2,p3,p4):
     #return (p1 + (p1-p2)/(1+(x**2*p3**2)))

#mymodel = np.polynomial.Polynomial.fit(frequencydata, conductivitydata, deg=6)
#print(mymodel)

init_guess = [1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]
init_guess2 = [1.0,1.0]
fit = curve_fit(model, frequencydata, rpermdata, p0=init_guess, absolute_sigma=True)
fit2 = curve_fit(model, frequencydata, conductivitydata, p0=init_guess, absolute_sigma=True)

ans, cov = fit
ans2, cov2 = fit2
fit_p1,fit_p2,fit_p3,fit_p4 = ans

#ftf2=2*pi*10**6/fit_p3

print("                                                                     ")
print("                                                                     ")
print(fit_p1)
print(fit_p2)
print(fit_p3)
print(fit_p4)
print("                                                                     ")
print("                                                                     ")

fit2_p1,fit2_p2,fit2_p3,fit2_p4 = ans2
final_cov = cov + cov2
cov_squared = np.sqrt(cov)
cov2_squared = np.sqrt(cov2)

x_line = np.arange(min(frequencydata), max(frequencydata), 1)
freq_y_line = model(x_line, fit_p1, fit_p2, fit_p3, fit_p4)
cond_y_line = model(x_line, fit2_p1, fit2_p2, fit2_p3, fit2_p4)
#cond_y_line = mymodel(x_line)
#Define relaxation for sample data.
relaxation_time = (1/2*pi*frequencydata)*((conductivitydata-(conductivity/2*pi*frequencydata*e0))/(rpermdata-fit_p2))
print(relaxation_time)

#cond_y_line = mymodel(x_line)
plt.plot(x_line, freq_y_line, '--', color='black',label="model (r-perm)") #comment this line out to just see conductivity
plt.plot(x_line, cond_y_line, '--', color='black',label="model (cond)") #comment this line out to just see relative permittivity
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I could not open the second file for reading because it is showing:

File ~\Documents\Akin\Antenna_Design\Dr Young\Dielectric_Extraction\CCT\555\250223\030323\FittingScript3.py:16 in 
experimentdata = np.array(rawdata[1:],dtype=float)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

Comment: Please show the code for your attempts so far.

Comment: And yes, please show experimental data so that your problem is reproducible.

Comment: I have included my codes and a link to the data file as it is a bit lengthy.  Many thanks

Comment: e0=0.000000000008845 is a potential transcription error. Is this supposed to be the permittivity of a vacuum?

Comment: I highly doubt that `water2.csv` has accurate units. The frequency axis seems to be in Hz and not MHz, and you probably shouldn't multiply in 1e6.

Answer (score 0):

Several things:

- Don't define pi and e0 yourself; those are defined in numpy and scipy respectively
- Don't use the `csv` module; use `np.loadtxt`
- Don't multiply 10**6 into your data. The data in `water2` are already in Hz.
- Report your axis as `Hz`, not `MHz` (or divide out 1e9 and report GHz).
- Drastically simplify your model. A quadratic is a good fit.
- Don't use the same colour (black) for two series.
- Don't `arange` a frequency axis; just reuse your frequency data.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.constants
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


e0 = scipy.constants.epsilon_0

(
    frequency_data, rperm_data, conductivity_data,
) = np.loadtxt('water2.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows=1).T

conductivity = 2*np.pi*e0 * frequency_data * conductivity_data


def model(x: np.ndarray, a: float, b: float, c: float) -> np.ndarray:
    return a*(x - b)**2 + c


ans, _ = curve_fit(
    f=model,
    xdata=frequency_data,
    ydata=rperm_data,
    p0=(-1e-20, 0, 100),
)
ans2, _ = curve_fit(
    f=model,
    xdata=frequency_data,
    ydata=conductivity_data,
    p0=(-1e-20, 1e10, 100),
)
fit_p1, fit_p2, fit_p3 = ans
print('Permittivity model parameters:', ans)
print('Conductivity model parameters:', ans2)

perm_y_line = model(frequency_data, *ans)
cond_y_line = model(frequency_data, *ans2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('Fitted model for group I phantom design.')
ax.set_xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ax.set_ylabel('Relative permittivity')
ax.plot(frequency_data, rperm_data, color='blue', label='r-perm')
ax.plot(frequency_data, perm_y_line, '--', color='yellow', label='r-perm (model)')
ax.plot(frequency_data, conductivity_data, color='orange', label='cond')
ax.plot(frequency_data, cond_y_line, '--', color='black', label='cond (model)')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

```
Permittivity model parameters: [-1.81253984e-19  0.00000000e+00  7.82664068e+01]
Conductivity model parameters: [-8.36734263e-20  2.38248964e+10  4.73936229e+01]
```

[image: quadratic fit plot]

If we force the use of the [Debye model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric#Debye_relaxation), then

- the sign of the second term is opposite to what you showed,
- the fit for permittivity remains good, but
- the fit for conductivity is somewhat poor:

```py
def model(f: np.ndarray, Einf: float, Estat: float, trelax: float) -> np.ndarray:
    return Einf + (Estat - Einf)/(1 + (2*np.pi*f*trelax)**2)


ans, _ = curve_fit(
    f=model,
    xdata=frequency_data,
    ydata=rperm_data,
    p0=(5, 10, 1e-12),
)
ans2, _ = curve_fit(
    f=model,
    xdata=frequency_data,
    ydata=conductivity_data,
    p0=(3, 2, 4e-11),
)
```

```
Permittivity model parameters: [ 5.26628904e+00  7.83236754e+01 -8.25540574e-12]
Conductivity model parameters: [2.88008607e+01 2.08642826e+00 3.81759369e-11]
```

[image: debye fit plot]

In this method, the permittivity model's parameters are found as

- Einf = 5.3,
- Estat = 78,
- relaxation tau = 8.3 ps.

### Second Dataset

Minor modifications. The error you had is due to junk rows at the end of the CSV that you should delete; then:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.constants
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


e0 = scipy.constants.epsilon_0

(
    frequency_data, rperm_data, conductivity_data, freq2, conduct2,
) = np.loadtxt('Fat-Mariyana-upto-20GHz.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows=1).T

frequency_data *= 1e9
freq2 *= 1e9


def model(f: np.ndarray, Einf: float, Estat: float, trelax: float) -> np.ndarray:
    return Einf + (Estat - Einf)/(1 + (2*np.pi*f*trelax)**2)


ans, _ = curve_fit(
    f=model,
    xdata=frequency_data,
    ydata=rperm_data,
    p0=(5, 5, 1e-11),
)
ans2, _ = curve_fit(
    f=model,
    xdata=frequency_data,
    ydata=conductivity_data,
    p0=(5, 5, 1e-11),
)
fit_p1, fit_p2, fit_p3 = ans
print('Permittivity model parameters:', ans)
print('Conductivity model parameters:', ans2)

perm_y_line = model(frequency_data, *ans)
cond_y_line = model(frequency_data, *ans2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('Fitted model for group I phantom design.')
ax.set_xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ax.set_ylabel('Relative permittivity')
ax.plot(frequency_data, rperm_data, color='blue', label='r-perm')
ax.plot(frequency_data, perm_y_line, '--', color='red', label='r-perm (model)')
ax.plot(frequency_data, conductivity_data, color='orange', label='cond')
ax.plot(frequency_data, cond_y_line, '--', color='black', label='cond (model)')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

```
Permittivity model parameters: [3.31493564e+00 4.74465430e+00 1.66561546e-11]
Conductivity model parameters: [5.72741877e+00 2.21991635e+00 1.56794845e-11]
```

[image: new fit plot]

Comment: Dear Reinderien,

Thanks for your suggestions and I find your comments very helpful.

1.  e0 is the permittivity of vacuum

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.

1.  e0 is the permittivity of vacuum

2.  The unit for the file Water2.csv is correct

3. Having fit the data using polynomials, the parameters found does not match reported values.  I wonder why the parameters are so far apart when compared to Debye.

4.  I could not read the newly attached file "Fat-Mariyana-upto-20GHz" in python because it is showing ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''  Link provided below.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BHHNlT2XmItGOanGl0xsyFjifPHor6To/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Ola examine the end of your CSV. Delete the junk rows and this works fine

Comment: Thank you very much Reinderien.  I have learnt another trick and put this under my belt.  I was busy looking for the error in my code.